# Ghostscript - how to suppress print dialog on Windows10 or Windows Server 2012

Tags: printing, ghostscript

I am invoking the following from a windows service under Windows 10 or Windows Server 2012 (C# program that shells out to execute the command), but nothing is being printed.  I can copy and paste the command being sent into a command prompt, but it pops up a print dialog and I have to click ok for the file to print (which it does).  What switch do I need to add such that the dialog won't come up and the file will be printed directly without user intervention since the intention is for this to work unattended as a windows service?  This is ghostscript 9.50, which is the latest as of today.  In an earlier version of ghostscript this worked if the device was set to ljet4 but this was causing an error with 9.50.  Also, the output file did not have the %printer% prefix on the outputfile and previously it was prefixed with \\spool\.  I have tried all of these combinations.  Is it the mswinpr2 that is causing the unwanted dialog?  I'm guessing this is what is preventing the printing to occur.

```
gswin64c -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies#1 -sDEVICE#mswinpr2 -sOutputFile#"%%printer%%HP LaserJet Professional P1109w" "\\2-DYQJKC2\c$\Webs\myfolder\Public\Reports\HIPAACert\189\H01519447A2191016103332.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mswinpr2 device needs to be able to select the Windows printer, yes. If it cannot for any reason (mistyping the printer name is a classic reason for example) then it will pop up the printer selection dialog. It has to otherwise it doesn't know where to send the output. I'd have to guess this is your problem (nothing to do with adding extra switches)

You should be using %printer% from the command line, you only need to double the % in a batch file, because batch file processing tries to interpret the % so you have to escape it. So if you are doubling the % in the command line then yes, it will indeed pop up a dialog box, because %printer% is not the same as %%printer%% so Ghostscript won't recognise this as a printer.

I'd suggest that you keep on working from the command line until you get a result, so don't double up the %.

Other than that, its difficult to comment. Do you get anything on the back channel (you'll want to drop the -q while debugging too) ? Obviously I'm not sitting in front of your system, so I can't see what the printer is called.....

FWIW I tried it here with the "Adobe PDF" printer and it works, but using the "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" does not, and in fact even selecting that from the dialog fails "Unable to open the initial device".

[edit]

A little debugging later....
The function DocumentProperties() fails with the Microsoft XPS Document Writer. I suspect this is because the printing system on Windows was significantly reworked for Vista and above, and Windows 10 does away with much of the legacy code. I suspect this old Win32 API call simply doesn't work with newer devices.

If your printer works when you select it from the print dialog, however, this is not the same problem. For me this printer fails even when selected from the print dialog. Seems its just not compatible with the old Win32 API.

NB this also displays the error "Printer StartDoc failed (error 00000006)".

So I still suspect that you have some problem with the printer name. Maybe a quick test would be to set the name to something really simple like '"Printer1' and try that.

I can't think of anything which has changed in the ljet4 device which would cause a problem, you don;t say what the error is, or even where it occurs, on the printer or reported by Ghostscript, so there's really nothing I can offer on that front.

Comment: I went back to using ljet4 instead of mswinpr2, and I also replaced the double percents with a single percent on the printer.  This is working.  I will now try to incorporate this knowledge back into the C# program.

Comment: It also appears that Ghostscript needs the full UNC name to the printer.  On our Windows 2008 server, we prefix the printer name with "\\spool\" (not using the %printer% variable - this was before my time).  On Server 2012R2, the "\\spool\" prefix does not work (gs thinks the printer name is a file and can't find it), but when I give the full UNC path to the printer (ie, prefix with "\\servername\printername" everything works and the file is printed successfully.  Lots of finicky parts to this.

Comment: That's because \\spool is only valid for the local machine. This is a Windows-ism, not really Ghostscript at all. I might point out that Ghostscript isn't intended as a print server (its a PostScript RIP), I'm sure there are products designed for the task available.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the same issue.  I added a -dQueryUser=3 argument.  The documentation on the use of -dQueryUser=N can be found at:
https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.25/Devices.htm#Win
in the
10.2 Supported options (device properties)
section.

The code that illustrates this, in a batch file on Windows 10, is:

```
SET MY_EXECUTABLE_PATH=C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\bin
for %%i in (*.pdf) do "%MY_EXECUTABLE_PATH%"\gswin64c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dPDFFitPage -dQueryUser=3 -sOutputFile="%printer%Printer_Name" "%%i"
```